# How to distribute a MacOS Disk Image (DMG) file to other Macs? Uploading to Google Drive or AwsS3 corrupts the file

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, dmg, google-drive-picker, apfs

I have created a DMG file and need to distribute it with a public link. Please note that the dmg file opens properly on all the macs if I transfer it through commandline scp (`OpenSSH`).

However, if I upload the same `DMG` file to `Google Drive` or `AWS S3`, and then redownload it to the same mac, it says the app has been damaged.

[image: Error]

What attributes change when the file is uploaded to `Google Drive` or `AWS S3`?

**Update-1**

Working DMG attibutes:

- com.apple.FinderInfo
- com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum
- com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
- com.apple.macl

Non Working DMG attributes:

- com.apple.diskimages.fsck
- com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum
- com.apple.macl
- com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
- com.apple.quarantine

Tried removing all attibutes by using xattr -cr . Yet the working dmg works, and the non-working dmg doesn't work

Comment: You could try MD5 checksumming the file before and after upload to see if the content has changed. And try checking the *"Extended Attributes"* to see if the metadata have changed.

Comment: Working DMG attibutes: 
com.apple.FinderInfo
com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum
com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
com.apple.macl

Comment: Non Working DMG attributes: com.apple.diskimages.fsck
com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum
com.apple.macl
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine

Comment: Update1 - Tried removing all attibutes by using xattr -cr <dmg-Name>. Yet the working dmg works, and the non-working dmg doesn't work

Comment: @MarkSetchell The md5 are indeed changed. But how to know what has changed?

Comment: Has the length of the file changed? `ls -l YOURFILE`

Comment: I think **7-zip** can read/verify DMG files. You could install it with `brew install p7zip` and see if it tells you anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS sometimes adds the quarantine attribute if it doesn't trusts the app even though it is signed.

Check it by running `xattr /path/to/app.app` in the terminal

if it contains the 'com.apple.quarantine' attribute, then probably you will get the above error in a dialogue-box.

To remove the attribute, run the below command before opening your DMG/App

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/app.app
```

To completely avoid this hassle, the app must be [notarized](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121742).

References:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/803598/app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened/
- https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/03/view-remove-extended-attributes-file-mac/